# CSS: How to get two DIVs side by side with automatic height, to the height of their container?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am designing a website for a client, and I am trying to get two side-by-side DIVs to adjust to 100% of their container. I've got the side-by-side done, but I can't get the right DIV to be the same height as the left one.

You can view the problem here: http://www.campusmomlaundry.com/

The "challenges" and "benefits" DIVs should be side-by-side and the same height, without manually specifying the height. How can I do this?

Comment: welcome to the mess that is CSS box model and layout... :-)

Comment: -1 for posting with link to live site that no longer exists

Comment: Really? -1 for a dead link that was posted almost TWO YEARS ago?

Comment: -1 for adding a link of which you _knew_ it wouldn't exist anymore after a while. Yes, almost three years later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the outer div is sizing automatically by the inner content, which is sizing automatically by its content.

You have couple of options:

- Use the background solution mentioned in the @R0MANARMY answer to create the visual ilusion of two equally tall columns.
- Set the height of the two inner divs to be the same exact number (using px or em)
- Set the height of the outer div to an exact number.
- Play with the `display` attribute and try couple of different values like table-cell and so on. Keep in mind that this one is not going to work in some older browsers. (Not only IE, but some old Firefox and Chrome releases as well)
- Use simple table with one row and two columns.

I realize that the last one is the most controversial of all. Yet it is a possible solution for your problem and there's no reason why you shouldn't at least evaluate.

([groan] please, please, nobody mention the words "semantic HTML"! there's no such thing in our universe.)

Comment: I ended up using jQuery to automatically synchronize the heights of the DIVs to each other... which is a hack... but I guess tables are less of a hack despite being considered poor design by myself and many. In fact I think I should probably use tables. Better to break away from best design than to use a total hack I guess.

Answer (score 2):

There's an article on A List Apart on solving a similar problem, you could probably use that as a reference: [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Comment: This is the best option I think. Next is using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me. I would solve this problem via javascript. Using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com) you could do...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($('#leftColumn').height() > $('#rightColumn').height())
{
    $('#rightColumn').height($('#leftColumn').height());
}
else
{
    $('#leftColumn').height($('#rightColumn').height());
}
});
```

That should do it. If your like the people I work with, and you don't like using Javascript for CSS problems. Then you are probably flat out of luck. Alot of the time, it is much faster just to use JQuery, then to use the "right way" using css. You could probably spend all day trying to get it to work with different combinations of styles.

Comment: I did do that, but please change your code to $(window).load, since I tried $(document).ready and that fires too quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps number of bullet points in the left DIV?

Comment: I'm definitely not a web developer.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried: `height: auto;` or `height: 100%;`?