# Why isn't my DIV children the same height as parent

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with this for awhile now, and I can't seem to find any solution.
I have a **frame**, a **top box**, a **left box** and a **right box** and a **middle box** containing the last two.

I want these to be the height of the **frame** minus the height of the **top box**. This would result in the frame being filled, nothing more and nothing left.

What is wrong with my current code, and what would be a proper way to achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #frame {
                width: 800px;
                min-height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #top {
                width: 800px;
                height: 80px;
                float: left;
                background-color: #666;
            }

            #middle {
                width: 800px;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }

            #left {
                width: 200px;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                background-color: #B3B4BD;
            }

            #right {
                width: 600px;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                background-color: #99BC99;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frame">
            <div id="top">Top</div>

            <div id="middle">
                <div id="left">Left</div>
                <div id="right">Right</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to float "middle" - it has nothing beside it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a 100% height unless you explicitly set the parent's height. The reason is that the parent normally expands in height to fit its children, and you need to specify an exact height so that the parent knows what its height is in time for its children to need it.

That said, there are a number of ways of achieving a similar effect. For instance if one div is normally taller than the other then you can use absolute positioning to stretch the second div to the same height. Or if you're really desperate then you can use a table.

Comment: Can you name some of these ways? I can't make a working example just yet

Comment: @PatrickReck This seems to be a popular question on Stack Overflow. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050571/ will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using proportions instead of exact pixels.

```
        #frame {
         width: 80%;
         min-height: 500px;
         border: 1px solid black;
         margin-right:auto;
         margin-left:auto;

        }

        #top {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #666;
        }

        #middle {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        #left {
            width: 33%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background-color: #B3B4BD;
        }

        #right {
            width: 66%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background-color: #99BC99;
        }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPwAs/)

Here's a screenshot of your demo with the updated CSS:
[image: Screenshot of your demo with updated CSS]

Comment: Yeah that yields kind of the same result as the original code, as you can see on the borders, it's still way off

Comment: My apologies.  You can't specify percentage heights on children elements unless their parent is also specified.  If you make sure you specify that parent height your children will fill the rest in.