# Bootstrap two column layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/settingsStyles/generalSettings.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="assignment3App">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                      <h5> Language: </h5> 
                      <h5> Phone numbers: </h5> 
                      <h5> Maximum page size: </h5> 
                      <h5> Default reply behavior: </h5> 
                      <h5> Undo Send: </h5> 
                      <h5> Signature: </h5> 
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-10 rightPane">
                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> Gmail display language: </h5> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> Default country code:  </h5> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Show conversations per page</h5> 
                      <h5> Show contacts per page</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Reply </h5> 
                      <h5> Reply all</h5> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Enable Undo Send </h5> 
                      <h5> Send cancellation period: </h5> 
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> No signature </h5> 
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

GeneralSettings.css

```
div div {
    background-color: #EAE7E7;
}

.rightPane div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BAB7B7;
}

.rightPane div:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

This is how the page is rendering:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1) Is there a way to make the left column content align exactly with the right column content?

2) When the window size is reduced, the right column content is pushed under the left column content. I do not want this to happen. I just want the width of the columns to be reduced. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the updated jsfiddle with the including bootstrap css and js

[Updated Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nozz5mwb/1/)

**UPDATE - First Question**

I used bootstrap tables instead of the fluid two column layout to achieve the same height of rows in the left and right columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>General Settings</h2>            
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="success">
          <td>Language</td>
          <td>Gmail display language:</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
          <td>Phone numbers:</td>
          <td>Default country code:</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="info">
          <td>Maximum page size: </td>
          <td>Show conversations per page <br> Show contacts per page</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="success">
          <td>Default reply behavior:</td>
          <td>Reply <br> Reply all</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
          <td>Undo Send:</td>
          <td>Enable Undo Send <br>  Send cancellation period:</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="info">
          <td>Signature:  </td>
          <td> No signature</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: i am not able to understand could you please explain more.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara I have edited my question. Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: I would recommend use table. If you don't want to push column under each other. So it's best to use table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), this is quite simple. Use the `col-xs-X` classes instead of `col-md-X`.

With `col-xs` you tell Bootstrap to use the specified column widths on the smallest devices (and larger ones if no other `col-` classes are present). With `col-md` you specify that columns should be used down to medium screens, but not on smaller ones. Bootstrap then stacks the columns on smaller screens.

See the [docs on grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)  for an overview.

For (1), I think the simplest solution would be to just mimic the stucture with the same elements. However, with wrapping text this will still be misaligned. Then you have basically two options:

- Assign the elements a fixed height. This may or may not be suitable in your case.
- Do some JavaScript trickery to synchronize the element heights on both sides. If you want to go down that road, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3050686/219187) may provide a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. My second question is solved. Do you know why by using `col-xs` the right columns are not pushed under the left ones?

Answer (score 1):

Added `col-xs-6` for your column div.

```css
div div {
 background-color: #EAE7E7;
}

.rightPane div {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #BAB7B7;
}

.rightPane div:last-child {
 border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                      <h5> Language: </h5> 
                      <h5> Phone numbers: </h5> 
                      <h5> Maximum page size: </h5> 
                      <h5> Default reply behavior: </h5> 
                      <h5> Undo Send: </h5> 
                      <h5> Signature: </h5> 
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-6 rightPane">
                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> Gmail display language: </h5> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> Default country code:  </h5> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Show conversations per page</h5> 
                      <h5> Show contacts per page</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Reply </h5> 
                      <h5> Reply all</h5> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                      <h5> Enable Undo Send </h5> 
                      <h5> Send cancellation period: </h5> 
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-10"> 
                        <h5> No signature </h5> 
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your first question just wrap your code like this i think this how you will be able to achieve your first one

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="container">
                      <h5> Language: </h5> 
                      <h5> Phone numbers: </h5> 
                      <h5> Maximum page size: </h5> 
                      <h5> Default reply behavior: </h5> 
                      <h5> Undo Send: </h5> 
                      <h5> Signature: </h5> 
              </div>
</div>
```

[Look demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nozz5mwb/3/)

Comment: @Michelle checkout your first option is it like this.?

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for you check out:
somehow it's not working in fiddle because bootstrap is not connecting with it. copy the whole code and paste it in your html and this definitely works. (remember don't forget to connect bootstrap with your html).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row tableAlign">
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane"> 
                    <h5> Language: </h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane">
                    <h5> Gmail display language: </h5> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane">     
                    <h5> Phone numbers: </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane">
                    <h5> Default country code:  </h5> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane">         
                    <h5> Maximum page size: </h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane">
                    <h5> Show conversations per page</h5> 
                    <h5> Show contacts per page</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane"> 
                    <h5> Default reply behavior: </h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane"> 
                    <h5> Reply </h5> 
                    <h5> Reply all</h5> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane"> 
                    <h5> Undo Send: </h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane"> 
                    <h5> Enable Undo Send </h5> 
                    <h5> Send cancellation period: </h5> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="col-xs-2 leftPane"> 
                    <h5> Signature: </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 rightPane"> 
                    <h5> No signature </h5> 
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
        background-color: #EAE7E7;
    }

    .tableAlign .rightPane, .tableAlign .leftPane  {
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
    }
    .tableAlign .rightPane{
        border-bottom:1px solid #BAB7B7;
    }

    @media (max-width:1199px) {
        .tableAlign .leftPane {
            width:20%;
        }
        .tableAlign .rightPane {
            width:70%;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:992px) {
        .tableAlign .leftPane {
            width:25%;
        }
        .tableAlign .rightPane {
            width:75%;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:720px) {
        .tableAlign .leftPane {
            width:30%;
            padding-right:15px;
        }
        .tableAlign .rightPane {
            width:70%;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:479px) {
        .tableAlign .leftPane {
            width:40%;
        }
        .tableAlign .rightPane {
            width:60%;
        }
    }
```

[image]